# I'm getting &#160; value at the end of string

Tags: c#, character-encoding, null, trim

I'm getting `&#160;` value at the end of string while fetching data from mysql DB.

How to handle it in ASP or c# - I tried using Trim in both c# and SQL nothing changed.

eg : If my data is sample, after fetching into textbox, I'm getting sample `&#160;`.

Please share your ideas to handle, Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a reproducable example of your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&#160;` is a nonbreaking space. It’s also html encoded as `&nbsp;`. In C# string literals it’s written as `\u00a0`.

I guess the character at the end of your string is not encoded in your string, but instead present as a single character. In that case `myString.RTrim({‘\u00a0’})` will most likely remove it.

If it is encoded, you might try

```
HttpUtility.HTMLEncode(
     HttpUtility.HTMLDecode(
         myString.RTrim({‘\u00a0’})
)
```

to remove it. But, if that is the case you should also figure out your application’s rules for storing HTML text. Is it stored encoded, with the ampersand-xxx-semicolon representation? Or is it stored as decoded Unicode?